# query filtering with Rails has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple question on RoR about many to many relationship(`has_many through:`). So I have a `Tweet` model, which has many `Tag` and vice versa.

You have an index action and view, where you show all tweets with tags, but you also have filtering by tags. Also there's a little detail, that a `Tweet` can be without a tag.

So if I do something like this:

`Tweet.includes(:tags).where(tags: { name: #2017 })`

If you then filter, you'll get only the tag, that you filtered, but not all the tags, that there was for `Tweet`. F.e. if `Tweet` had tags `#2017, #2016, #2015`, in the end you'll get only `#2017` in your view.

So you can fix the problem with doing something like this:

`Tweet.joins(:tags).where(tags: { name: #2017 })`

Then you'll get all tags for every tweet.

But the problem is that, if index page has no filters, I want all tweets to show, event without a tag.

Of course you can do a hack like checking if tag param exists do `Tweet.joins` else do `Tweet.includes`.

Are there a way to do this within 1 query and without hacks? Also what's the mechanics behind this. I understand the logic behind `includes or LEFT OUTER JOIN`, because it just maps `tweet_id` and ’tag_id’ in your intermediate table and then this id to `Tag` table, when you have something like `where` query mentioned upper. But, why with `INNER JOIN` it keeps me giving all tags, gives me question.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

Its because `includes` does the eager loading, when you query

```
Tweet.includes(:tags).where(tags: {name: "2017"})
```

It eager loads all the tweets with tags name as 2017. `Tweet.tags` will not run the db query again and will have only one value for tags.

But in case of joins

```
Tweet.joins(:tags).where(tags: {name: "2017"})
```

It does the innner join, and find only those tweets which have tags and tag name is 2017. After finding the tweets when you do `Tweet.tags`, it runs the db query again to find all the associated tags which gives you the desired result.